# Configure JasperReports to print barcode in margin of each page

Tags: jasper-reports

We have an application that uses JasperReports to print multi-page reports.  We have a requirement to print a barcode on each page of the report.  The position of the code is around 40 mm from the top of the left hand side.  This is important for scanning.  Is this possible as the barcode is outside the bands (in the margin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution:

I added the barcode to the background band

```
<background>
</background>
```